# trouble setting up credentials in Spotipy

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm trying to run some simple code from the Spotipy docs:

```
scope = 'user-library-read'

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print ("Usage: %s username" % (sys.argv[0],))
    sys.exit()

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)
```

I've already tried to set up my credentials in my terminal (Ubuntu) by running:

`$ export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID='[my id]'`

`$ export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET='[my secret]'`

`$ export SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI='localhost:8888/callback'`

Still, I get this:

```
  You need to set your Spotify API credentials. You can do this by
            setting environment variables like so:

            export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID='your-spotify-client-id'
            export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET='your-spotify-client-secret'
            export SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI='your-app-redirect-url'

            Get your credentials at     
                https://developer.spotify.com/my-applications

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SpotifyException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e24370a9caf8> in <module>()
      7     sys.exit()
      8 
----> 9 token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

/home/user/anaconda3/envs/Python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spotipy/util.py in prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)
     45                 https://developer.spotify.com/my-applications
     46         ''')
---> 47         raise spotipy.SpotifyException(550, -1, 'no credentials set')
     48 
     49     sp_oauth = oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, 

SpotifyException: http status: 550, code:-1 - no credentials set
```

What am I doing wrong? I haven't been able to find a clean rundown of how to fix this anywhere.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `$ export SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI='ocalhost:8888/callback'` .... `ocalhost`?

Comment: That's a typo, sorry, edited

Comment: try to define credentials directly in python: `util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)`

Comment: @sKwa that does indeed give me a prompt, thanks. But I get this message: `User authentication requires interaction with your web browser. Once you enter your credentials and give authorization, you will be redirected to a url.  Paste that url you were directed to to complete the authorization.` If I enter the URL I get `SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request`.

Comment: how do you run your script? try to ask variable in `ipython` before running your code: `os.getenv('<YOUR VARIABLE>')`. may be you use different terminal sessions and variables are not exported, i.e. do `export ...` -> `ipython` -> run code.

Comment: @snapcrack, about `Bad Request` its another question, follow this [link](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/tutorial/) to get your client id,secret and callback uri.

Comment: @sKwa i'm running the scripe in a notebook. i just ran `os.getenv('[myvariable]')` with all three and I'm still getting the same error as I got from the original question. I'm stumped

Comment: @sKwa now i'm just getting "Error 
Oops! Something went wrong, please try again or check out our help area." there seems to be no guidance on this anywhere and the docs are incredibly confusing

Comment: if you are simply reading a library, you don't need this authorization flow. use `ClientCredentials()` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are struggling to use the environment vars you can try using `configparser` instead:

```
import configparser

import spotipy
import spotipy.oauth2 as oauth2

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')
client_id = config.get('SPOTIFY', 'CLIENT_ID')
client_secret = config.get('SPOTIFY', 'CLIENT_SECRET')


auth = oauth2.SpotifyClientCredentials(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

token = auth.get_access_token()
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

The `config.cfg` should look like this:

```
[SPOTIFY]
CLIENT_ID=xxxx
CLIENT_SECRET=xxxx
```

If you're using a `git` repository add:

```
*.cfg
```

To the `.gitignore` so your keys aren't included into the repo.

Comment: "Note that this method does not need any scope/redirect url and will only allow access to publicly available information." - https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/194